# Algorithms to represent a set of integers with only one integer

Tags: algorithm, integer, set

This may not be a programming question but it's a problem that arised recently at work. Some background: big C development with special interest in performance.

I've a set of integers and want to test the membership of another given integer. I would love to implement an algorithm that can check it with a minimal set of algebraic functions, using only a integer to represent the whole space of integers contained in the first set.

I've tried a composite Cantor pairing function for instance, but with a 30 element set it seems too complicated, and focusing in performance it makes no sense. I played with some operations, like XORing and negating, but it gives me low estimations on membership. Then I tried with successions of additions and finally got lost.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the range of the integers ?

Comment: Note that an integer with 32 bits, can represent a set that can contain up to 32 elements (the range contains up to 32 elements). The reason is if you have k>32 possible elements, there are 2^32 possible sets, and from pigeonhole principle - two sets will be mapped to the same integer.

Comment: Sorry for not clearing the domain up: they're 30 bit long unsigned integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sets of `unsigned long` of size 30, the following is one fairly obvious way to do it:

- store each set as a sorted array, `30 * sizeof(unsigned long)` bytes per set.
- to look up an integer, do a few steps of a binary search, followed by a linear search (profile in order to figure out how many steps of binary search is best - my wild guess is 2 steps, but you might find out different, and of course if you test `bsearch` and it's fast enough, you can just use it).

So the next question is why you want a big-maths solution, which will tell me what's wrong with this solution other than "it is insufficiently pleasing".

I suspect that any big-math solution will be slower than this. A single arithmetic operation on an N-digit number takes at least linear time in N. A single number to represent a set can't be very much smaller than the elements of the set laid end to end with a separator in between. So even a linear search in the set is about as fast as a single arithmetic operation on a big number. With the possible exception of a Goedel representation, which could do it in one division once you've found the `n`th prime number, any clever mathematical representation of sets is going to take multiple arithmetic operations to establish membership.

Note also that there are two different reasons you might care about the performance of "look up an integer in a set":

- You are looking up lots of different integers in a single set, in which case you *might* be able to go faster by constructing a custom lookup function for that data. Of course in C that means you need either (a) a simple virtual machine to execute that "function", or (b) runtime code generation, or (c) to know the set at compile time. None of which is necessarily easy.
- You are looking up the same integer in lots of different sets (to get a sequence of all the sets it belongs to), in which case you might benefit from a combined representation of all the sets you care about, rather than considering each set separately.

I suppose that very occasionally, you might be looking up lots of different integers, each in a different set, and so neither of the reasons applies. If this is one of them, you can ignore that stuff.

Comment: Maybe you're right and I'm in a lost quest for a "pleasant" math solution, but I'll sleep like a baby if I find one ;)

Comment: It took me a few hours but you finally convinced me.

Answer (score 0):

One good start is to try [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).
Basically, it's a probabilistic data structure that gives you no false negative, but some false positive. So when an integer matches a bloom filter, you then have to check if it really matches the set, but it's a big speedup by reducing a lot the number of sets to check.

Comment: Bloom filters use multiple bitsets, I am not sure it fits here.

Comment: That's a method to test membership of an element in a set. I'm not sure I understood the whole problem, but it seems that's a membership problem :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, a Bloom filter is a way to *speed up* membership testing, you still need to implement the fallback test :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Right :-) (that's in my answer ;-) )

Comment: From personal experience - bloom filters are usually good for huge/infinite range of elements, and require much more then 32 bits to be effective. If someone have ever encountered something different - I'll be glad to hear about it.

Comment: @amit: I certainly agree that 32 bits is too small a filter -- it's only 1 bit per element of the set, which I think gives you a best possible false positive rate of about 50% or so. Also, computing several independent well-distributed hashes is a slow-ish operation itself, so not necessarily worth doing in order to avoid something that's only slow-ish (lookup in a 30 integer set) rather than very slow (e.g. connecting to the internet in order to ask some server whether the integer is in the set). I wouldn't be surprised if you're right and a Bloom filter doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

if i'd understood your correctly, python example:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>>
>>>
>>> len_a = len(a)
>>> b = [1]
>>> if len(set(a) - set(b)) < len_a:
...     print 'this integer exists in set'
...
this integer exists in set
>>>
```

math base: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram

Comment: This would only work with constant successions like [Xi | Xi = Xi-1 + 1]. I'm looking for something that looks in sets like [30, 40, 120]

Comment: It does work on all sets, `len(set(a) - set([1]) < len(a)` is just a funny way of saying `1 in set(a)`, because if `1` isn't in `a`, then `set(a) - set(b) == set(a)` and hence has the same length as `a`. Introducing the set difference appears to me to be a way to satisfy the requirement in the question, "must have spurious mathematical basis" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop i'd write this statments (`len(....<`) instead of `in` because SO may be not understood python.

Comment: Ok, I see it now, sorry. Yes, but simplifying the code does not make it suitable for the task I've in mind :)